# Passing state from parent to children in React Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, parent, children

I am a beginner in React and I am facing an issue to pass a state from parent to children.
That's my code :

```
import Footer from './Footer';
import Header from "./Header";

export default function Layout({setPage, children}) {
    return <>
        <Header setPage={setPage}/>
            {children}
        <Footer/>
    </>
}
```

At this step, I get the setPage state and I can pass it successfully to the Header component for example. However, {children} don't get it. Is there a way to pass the setPage state to {children} ?

Thanks,

I tried useContext hook but didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using this Layout component to wrap certain pages content, I don't think you'll need to do this. Follow along:

Probably, you'll use this component as follows:

```
import { useState } from "React";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import OtherComponent from "../components/OtherComponent";

export default function HomePage() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState();

  return (
    <Layout setPage={setPage}>
      <OtherComponent setPage={setPage}/>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Because you'll need to know which children will use that prop. React does have [some ways to do this that you asked](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Children#children-map), but it's discouraged as it fit a super small set of cases.

Keep up learning, good luck!

**Edit 1**: To complement the usage, you can change what is rendered on the screen using that state like this:

```
/* previous imports */
import YetOtherComponent from "../components/YetOtherComponent";

export default function HomePage() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0); /* setting the default inside the parenthesis */

  return (
    <Layout setPage={setPage}>
      {page === 1 /* checking which component should render */
        ? (<OtherComponent setPage={setPage}/>)
        : page === 2
        ? (<YetOtherComponent setPage={setPage}/>)
        : /* As many options as you want */
      }
      
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

This way not all of them would display at all times, only when the respective page value is equal to the component that must be shown.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it worked but now I have all components to which I passed the state displayed at the same time. My project is a single page website... Do you have an idea about how to fix this ? Thanks again !

Comment: I added an edit trying to answer your follow up question. Let me know if it still lacks some information for you.

Comment: Big thanks man ! Completely solved my issue and now it is more clear to me how the useState's mechanism work

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve the objective. Described below is one rather fundamental / rudimentary method.

Layout component:

```
import Footer from './Footer';
import Header from "./Header";

export default function Layout({setPage, children}) {
    return <>
        <Header setPage={setPage}/>
            {children}
        <Footer/>
    </>
}
```

Parent / page where layout component is included:

```
import Layout from './Layout';

export default function SomePage(props) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState();
  return <>
    <Layout setPage={setPage}>
      <SomeChild1 setPage={setPage} />
      <SomeChild2 setPage={setPage} />
      <SomeOtherChild />
    </Layout>
  </>
}
```

In this way, the `setPage` method is passed to each child where it is required. `SomeChild1` and `SomeChild2` both have the `setPage` sent as prop. Whereas `SomeOtherChild` does not require the prop and therefore does not have it.